# Can I use a table as background and add a different table on top of it?

Tags: css, html, html-email

I am working on an email template so my options are limited to tables.

I need a way to achieve the following using tables
[image]

All content is generated dynamically via RSS feed so I cannot use images.

Here's what I have so far

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" st-sortable="banner"><tbody><tr>
    <td>
      <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth"><tbody><tr>
    <td width="100%">
       <table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="devicewidth"><tbody><tr>
    <!-- start of image --><td align="center">     *|FEEDBLOCK:http://domain.com/feed/|* *|FEEDITEMS:[$count=1]|*
      <a target="_blank" href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*">*|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|*</a>
     </td>
     </tr></tbody></table>
    <!-- end of image -->
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td width="100%">
      <table width="150" align="left" bgcolor="#ff4800" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="devicewidth"><tbody><tr>
    <!-- start of title --><td align="left">*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|*</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
    <!-- start of content -->
      <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff">*|FEEDITEM:CONTENT|* </td>
         </tr>
           </tbody></table>
    <!-- end of title -->
    </td>
       </tr>
                      <!-- Spacing -->
    <tr><td height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;"></td></tr>
    <!-- Spacing -->
    </tbody></table>
    </td>
          </tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can always do that. I have tried to get some similar kind of layout with respect to the screen-shot in your post.

**You may check this code**

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>My Layout</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
table{
border:1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
td{
border:1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
#table1{
width: 800px;
}
.table1-td-left{
height:400px;
width:200px;
background-color: green;
}
.table1-td-right{
width:600px;
background-color: yellow;
}
.table2-td-left{
background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
}
.table2-td-right{
background-color: blue;
    width: 300px;
}
</style> 
</head> 

<body> 
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td class="table1-td-left">LHS</td>
        <td class="table1-td-right">
            <table id="table2">
                <tr>
                    <td class="table2-td-left">Content # 1</td>
                    <td class="table2-td-right">Content # 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

You may also see this [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/npralhad/ddyh7320/).

**Basically you need to table within `td`.**

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. The problem with my structure is that I need to show an image in `<td class="table1-td-right">` and that pushes the `table2` down.

Comment: In that can you will need to change the `width` values in the css classes according to your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved, however, know that background images are not supported in Outlook 2003, 2007, and 2013.  If you are not looking to support those email clients here is how you can achieve this.  Disclaimer: this should be tested in Litmus or Email on Acid to verify the email clients you wish to support are producing the results you intended.

```
<table width="620" height="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" background="http://ingridwu.dmmdmcfatter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/placeholder.png">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top: 75px;">
            <table width="200" bgcolor="#dddddd" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2>Title</h2></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Some text</p></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can also view it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fcpz1um2/

Comment: Yes, that was another solution I considered but the background image is generated through RSS feed so it's not supported at all.

Comment: bummer.  I'm not too familiar with RSS emails.  I'll have to do a little more research.

Answer (score 0):

using the backgrounds.cm method, you can do something like below sample and it should work in about 99% of email clients. It will need media queries and such to make it responsive, but should render consistently - even in ALL Outlooks.

```
<table width="620">
<tr>
<td background="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDVdU.png" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" width="100%" height="300" valign="top" style="-webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; background-position:center; background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDVdU.png); background repeat: no-repeat;">
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:660px;height:250px;">
    <v:fill type="frame" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDVdU.png" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
                        <div style="text-align:left;">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <td height="34" style="font-size:1px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table align="left" width="230" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="vertical-align:bottom; max-width:430px;">
                            <tr>
                            <td style="padding-left:5px;">
                            <table align="left" bgcolor="red" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="vertical-align:bottom; max-width:430px;">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:67px; line-height:80px; padding:5px;">30% <span style="font-size:40px;">Off</span></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td bgcolor="#000000" style="color:#FFFFFF; padding:5px;">HURRY UP! GRAB YOUR BITE</td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
                      </td>
</tr>
</table>
```